# Can't display a map api in phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

Greetings I tried to integrate http://mapas.sapo.pt/api in android with phonegap but all that I was getting was a Blank Space.

I am noob into phone gap and I would be very please if someone could give me a little explanation why does it happen ;)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when rendering a Google Map in a phonegap app.  It turned out that the **navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition** was not working properly *(phonegap 0.9.5, android 3)*.

To fix the problem I added Geolocation.usePhoneGap() in the deviceready callback:

```
function onDeviceReady() {         
      Geolocation.usePhoneGap()   
}

function onLoad() {
      document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}
```